# error_get_last function is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception, error-handling

I am creating a global error handler in code igniter for this I have created a **pre_system** type hook and my hook class code is as follows

```
 <?php
    class PHPFatalError {
    
    public function setHandler() {
           register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');
        }
    }
function handleShutdown() {     
    
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(error_get_last()); 
         
         }
```

but error_get_last this function is not working in codeigniter.
Can any one help me in this

Comment: You forgot to explain what "not working" means, but you're registering a standalone function when you actually have a class method.

Comment: This function is running but error_get_last() is returning null.